# What will be the result of the following insertion in a B+ tree ?

Tags: database, indexing, b-tree

I was going through the algorithm to insert keys in a B+ tree based indexing scheme. Suppose initially the tree is empty, and the values are inserted in order are- 73,108,100,120,125,105. I proceeded as follows-
INSERT 73

[image]

INSERT 108

[image]

INSERT 100

[image]

INSERT 120

[image]

INSERT 125

[image]

According to my professor, this insertion should result in something like-
(120 linked with 125, and no key value of 125 in the level above, in case the image's not clear)

[image]

INSERT 105
This is where I got confused. I am having three different results, depending on whether I follow my professor's algo,follow my instinct, or follow an online simulation tool which animates the insertions in B+ tree)

My solution-
[image]

My professors' soln-
[image]

Online tool's soln-

[image]

Can someone guide me and tell me which of the above solutions is/are correct ?

Comment: In the professors solution, is there really no link from the upper level to the bottom right node with 125? B-tree nodes cannot have no link from a parent node.